# If f,g agree almost everywhere, then $\underset{\mathbb{R}^d}{\underline{\int}} f(x) =\underset{\mathbb{R}^d}{\underline{\int}} g(x)$

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

This is an exercise from **Terry Tao's Introduction to Measure Theory - Exercise 1.3.10 part (iv)**. The question is:

If f,g agree almost everywhere, then $\underset{\mathbb{R}^d}{\underline{\int}} f(x) \operatorname{d}\!{x}=\underset{\mathbb{R}^d}{\underline{\int}} g(x) \operatorname{d}\!{x}$

This is my solution but I feel uncertain about it, in particularly when I consider each $E_i$ to be a subset of $A \cup A^c$ (see equation **(1)**). What do you think?:

Define $A$ such that $m(A^c)=0$
$$A=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^d : f(x)=g(x)\}$$
We have $\underset{\mathbb{R}^d}{\underline{\int}} f(x) \operatorname{d}\!{x}=\underset{\mathbb{R}^d}{\underline{\int}} g(x) \operatorname{d}\!{x}$ if and only if $\underset{\mathbb{R}^d}{\underline{\int}} |f-g|(x) \operatorname{d}\!{x}=0$. Then

\begin{align*}
\underset{\mathbb{R}^d}{\underline{\int}} |f-g|(x) \operatorname{d}\!{x} &=
\sup_{0 \leq p \leq |f-g|}{\sum^{k}_{i=0}a_{i}m(E_i)} \text{ with } E_{i} \subset A \cup A^c \subset \mathbb{R}^d \text{ } \bf{(1)}\\
&=\sup_{\substack{0 \leq p(x) \leq |f-g|(x) \\ x \in A \cup A^c}}{\sum^{k}_{i=0}a_{i}m(E_i)} (*)
\end{align*}
Since $A$ and $A^c$ is disjoint, $E_i$ must be contained in one of these sets. We'll split the above sum into the following:
$$\sum^{k}_{i=0}a_{i}m(E_i)=\sum^{k'}_{i=0 \ E_i \subset A}a_{i}m(E_i)+\sum^{k''}_{i=0 \ E_i \subset A^c}a_{i}m(E_i)$$
And hence we derive $p$ to be the sum of two simple functions
$$\underbrace{\sum^{k}_{i=0}a_{i}1_{E_i}}_{p}=\underbrace{\sum^{k'}_{i=0 \ E_i \subset A}a_{i}1_{E_i}}_{p'}+\underbrace{\sum^{k''}_{i=0 \ E_i \subset A^c}a_{i}1_{E_i}}_{p''}$$
Substituting the above into $(*)$ yields:
$$
\sup_{\substack{0 \leq p(x) \leq |f-g|(x) \\ x \in A \cup A^c}}{\left( \sum^{k'}_{i=0 \ E_i \subset A}a_{i}m(E_i)+\sum^{k''}_{i=0 \ E_i \subset A^c}a_{i}m(E_i) \right)}
$$
Since each sum is greater than $0$, the supremum of the sums is the sum of the supremums with respect to their simple functions
$$
\underset{\mathbb{R}^d}{\underline{\int}} |f-g|(x) \operatorname{d}\!{x}=\sup_{\substack{0 \leq p'(x) \leq |f-g|(x) \\ x \in A}}{\left( \sum^{k'}_{i=0 \ E_i \subset A}a_{i}m(E_i)\right)}+\sup_{\substack{0 \leq p''(x) \leq |f-g|(x) \\ x \in A^c}}{\left(\sum^{k''}_{i=0 \ E_i \subset A^c}a_{i}m(E_i)\right)}
$$
The right sum evaluates to $0$ since it considers each $E \subset A^c$ where $m(A^c)=0$. Similarly, the left sum evaluates to $0$. Indeed
$$
\forall x \in A \text{ } |f-g|(x)=0 \implies \forall x \text{ } \in A 0 \leq p'(x) \leq |f-g|(x)=0 \implies p'=0
$$
Therefore $\underset{\mathbb{R}^d}{\underline{\int}} |f-g|(x) \operatorname{d}\!{x}=0$, as needed. Proving the case with the upper integral uses the same arguments.

Comment: The equivalence doesn't hold

Comment: @Jakobian integral of f doesn't equal integral of g?